# Online to On Premise?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

So i'm trying to gather some information for my employer. Without diving into reasoning or great detail my question is;

Is it possible to migrate from SharePoint Online to On Premise? (Standard or Enterprise). If so, from a development perspective what is the upgrade path like/ How easily can this be done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can migrate from SharePoint online to Onprem but you need 3rd party tool for this purpose.

Because in SharePoint online you dont have access to SharePoint content database which you can move, also there are chances build version mismatch as SharePoint online always ahead of race.

You can try with Sharegate or Metalogix...they offer trial version as well.